# linear gradient css with deg with rest color to bottom and top

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I did linear 115deg for doing 2 colors, but for the rest, I can't make them be nested gradient from top to bottom, here is my result gradient [image: linear-gradient-i-did], the colors are : **white** and **#F5F5F5** ( grey )

I want the grey that has linear also from bottom to top to be white

is that possible?

the result might like this [image: linear-gradient-expected]

i did my own linear like the expected but with rgba to opacity it, using like this

```
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, #ffffff 68vw, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.5) 30vw);
```

i did this gradient for background color so i can put content inside the div
here is what i did => https://codepen.io/lpllplp222/pen/vYWPdBe

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clip-path` to cut out the part of the gradient you want to be visible.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

#do-linear {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 70% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="do-linear"></div>
```

Comment: i am using it for background color, if I use clip-path, the content on that div is also cropped :(

Comment: @Pocket add it as pseudo element

Comment: is that any example ?  @TemaniAfif